Was president Duda a steadfast supporter of asylum rights even when PiS was holding the cabinet?
AP:

Poland’s president on Wednesday condemned the government’s contentious plan to suspend the right to asylum for irregular migrants, calling it a “fatal mistake.”
President Andrzej Duda, whose approval is needed for the plan to take effect, argued in parliament that it would block access to safe haven for people in Russia and neighboring Belarus who oppose their governments. Prime Minister Donald Tusk replied that it would not apply to dissidents.

I know nothing about Duda's prior stances on asylum seekers and (irregular or illegal) immigrants. But I know that Tusk is from another party and they've had other disagreements. When Duda's party (PiS) was holding the cabinet, what were his positions on immigration and asylum?

Well, previous cabinets did not declare the will to suspend the right to asylum. The official stance of government was that the asylum seekers should follow the legal path of asking for asylum and storming the border is not the proper way to apply for asylum.

Have you read the Wikipedia article on Duda? It mentions some of his positions. You really should do some research before posting a question here.

@StuartF: actually I have in the meantime. It's not terribly conclusive. Back during the Syrian war peak he opposed the EU relocation scheme then 'voluntarily' agreed to a smaller number.

@StuartF: technically speaking those aren't even asylum seekers given EU's categorization, just given temp protection. So it's even less illuminating in that perspective.
